# Binding a Source to a asynchronous method

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

Hello I have this following code

```
    <controls:FlowListView x:Name="Board"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                  BackgroundColor="Black"
                  FlowColumnCount="3"
                  FlowItemTappedCommand="ExecuteAction">

    <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="GetImageGivenCard"></Image>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</controls:FlowListView>
```

This FlowListView ItemsSource will be a list of Cards. GetImageGivenCard would be a method which would acess a cache and retrieve an image given a designated card, all this asynchronously ofcourse (I'm using Akavache). Is what I'm trying to achieve possible ? If not, can you please give me some alternative solutions ?

Thank you for your time guys.

edit:

```
 Source="GetImageGivenCard"
```

This line doesn't work ofcourse, it's only pseudocode for showing you what I would be hoping to obtain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading
It is a good plugin (caching, async, imageloader, placeholder included)